# Retrieve returns from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a HTML file in `PAGE` directory called `Test-Page-1.html`. And in the root, I've a JavaScript file called `Script.Con.js`.

In the html file, I have this script:

```
 (function Flush () {
   var Customer = { 
      name: prompt("Your Name?"), 
      id: 10100 
      product_bought: prompt("What is it you want?"), 
      d_o_d_expected: prompt("When do you expect it?")}
   return "name: " + Customer.name + "\n" + 
   "id: " + Customer.id + "\n" + 
   "product: " + Customer.product_bought + "\n" + 
   "expected on: " + Customer.d_o_d_expected;
})
/** FORGIVE THE CODE'S CLUMSINESS **/
```

I want `Script.Con.js` to get the value returned by the `Flush()` function. I don't know how to do this, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can include [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) statement before calling IIFE by including `()` before or following last closing parenthesis to set identifier for value returned by IIFE

```
<script>
var result =  (function Flush () {
   var Customer = { 
      name: prompt("Your Name?"), 
      id: 10100, // missing `,` here
      product_bought: prompt("What is it you want?"), 
      d_o_d_expected: prompt("When do you expect it?")}
   return "name: " + Customer.name + "\n" + 
   "id: " + Customer.id + "\n" + 
   "product: " + Customer.product_bought + "\n" + 
   "expected on: " + Customer.d_o_d_expected;
}()); // `result` should be accessible by `Script.Con.js`
</script>
<script src="Script.Con.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Missed the omission at OP; also did not notice `Customer` object is also missing  comma `,` following `id: 10100` which logs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(...)`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the `()` thing was just an omission or intentionally deferring until/unless called.

Answer (score 0):

The way that's written, your `Script.Con.js` file's code **can't** call `Flush` — and neither can anything else, you've used a named function expression to create a function you never keep any reference to. NFEs don't even add the name to the current scope, so nothing can ever refer to that function.

You have a couple of options:

1. Make it a function *declaration* instead by removing the `()` around it, and then have `Script.Con.js` call it:

   ```
   function Flush () {
      var Customer = { 
         name: prompt("Your Name?"), 
         id: 10100 ,
         product_bought: prompt("What is it you want?"), 
         d_o_d_expected: prompt("When do you expect it?")}
      return "name: " + Customer.name + "\n" + 
      "id: " + Customer.id + "\n" + 
      "product: " + Customer.product_bought + "\n" + 
      "expected on: " + Customer.d_o_d_expected;
   }
   ```

   Then in `Script.Con.js`:

   ```
   var order = Flush();
   ```

   Note that the prompts won't happen until `Script.Con.js` calls `Flush()`.
2. Run it immediately and save the *result* in a variable, then have `Script.Con.js` use the variable:

   ```
   var order = (function Flush () {
      var Customer = { 
         name: prompt("Your Name?"), 
         id: 10100 ,
         product_bought: prompt("What is it you want?"), 
         d_o_d_expected: prompt("When do you expect it?")}
      return "name: " + Customer.name + "\n" + 
      "id: " + Customer.id + "\n" + 
      "product: " + Customer.product_bought + "\n" + 
      "expected on: " + Customer.d_o_d_expected;
   })();
   ```

   Note the `()` at the end to actually call it. That will trigger the `prompt`s immediately, and save the result to `order`. Then your `Script.Con.js` code would use the `order` variable directly.

---

Side Note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that non-constructor functions like this start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `flush` rather than `Flush`. (Also a bit confused about the name "flush" but...)

Side Note 2: You were missing a `,` after `id: 10100`. Added above.